# Centering content in the middle of the screen in a react native application

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i want to center my view at the center of the screen but its unable am using justifyContent: 'center',
alignItems: 'center', but its all unable to put the contents at the middle of the screen i want the content to go to middle of the screen

i want the buttons and the inputs all to be at the middle of the screen .
i have tried to align but its unable to

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useContext} from 'react';
import UserContext from './useContextStore';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  Button,
  TextInput,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Platform,
} from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import DataViewDoc from './view';

const PhoneInput = ({navigation}) => {
  const [number, setNumber] = useState({number: ''});
  const [value, loadedVal] = useState({value: true});
  const [screenDaetail, setScreenDaetail] = useState(true);

  const [waiting, setwaiting] = useState(false);
  const [code, setCode] = useState({code: '', number: ''});

  const [confirm, setConfirm] = useState(null);

  const [codee, setCodee] = useState('');
  // let num;

  const getNumber = (val) => {
    setNumber({number: val});
  };

  const getCode = (val) => {
    setCode({code: val, number: number.number});
  };
  //firebase**************************************************************************
  async function signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {
    const confirmation = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
    console.log('confirmation code is ', confirmation);
    setConfirm(confirmation);
  }

  async function confirmCode() {
    try {
      await confirm.confirm(codee).then(() => {
        console.log('logged in');
        // setScreenDaetail(!screenDaetail);
        navigation.navigate('codeForma');
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Invalid code.');
    }
  }

  return (
    <View styles={style.container}>
      {confirm ? (
        <>
          <View styles={style.content}>
            <Text style={style.TextStyle1}>Enter Valid Code </Text>
          </View>
          <View style={style.viewForText}>
            <TextInput
              style={style.textinput}
              onChangeText={(text) => setCodee(text)}
              secureTextEntry={true}
              maxLength={13}
              value={codee}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={style.viewForSend}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={style.SubmitButtonStyle}
              activeOpacity={0.1}
              onPress={() => {
                // sendPhoneCodeTwillio();

                confirmCode();
              }}>
              <Text style={style.TextStyle}> SEND</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity
              style={style.SubmitButtonStyle2}
              activeOpacity={0.1}
              onPress={() => {
                // sendPhoneTwilio();
                setConfirm(null);
              }}>
              <Text style={style.TextStyle}> Back </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <View styles={style.content}>
            <Text style={style.TextStyle1}>Enter Phone number </Text>
          </View>

          <View style={style.viewForText}>
            <TextInput
              style={style.textinput}
              onChangeText={(text) => {
                getNumber(text);
              }}
              maxLength={13}
              value={number.number}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={style.viewForSend}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={style.SubmitButtonStyle}
              activeOpacity={0.1}
              onPress={() => {
                signInWithPhoneNumber(number.number);
              }}>
              <Text style={style.TextStyle}> SEND </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity
              style={style.SubmitButtonStyle2}
              activeOpacity={0.1}
              onPress={() => {
                signInWithPhoneNumber(number.number);
              }}>
              <Text style={style.TextStyle}> RESEND </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    // paddingBottom: Platform.OS === 'android' ? 50 : 0,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  textinput: {
    margin: 25,
    borderColor: '#7a42f4',
    borderWidth: 5,
    borderRadius: 35,
    color: 'black',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontFamily: 'Cochin',
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  viewForText: {width: 250, alignSelf: 'center'},
  viewForSend: {
    width: 400,
    // alignSelf: 'baseline',
    borderRadius: 20,
    margin: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignSelf: 'center',
  },
  content: {
    // justifyContent: 'center',
    // // alignItems: 'flex-start',
    flex: 2,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    marginBottom: 36,
  },

  topTierblack: {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    borderRadius: 100,
    width: 300,
    marginLeft: 40,
    opacity: 0.5,
  },
  topTierRed: {
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    borderRadius: 100,
    width: 300,
    marginLeft: 40,
  },
  topTierGreen: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    borderRadius: 100,
    width: 300,
    marginLeft: 40,
    opacity: 0.5,
  },
  viewForSend2: {
    width: 200,
    alignSelf: 'flex-end',
    borderRadius: 20,
    // margin: 10,
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    width: '40%',
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginVertical: 30,
    color: 'red',
    borderRadius: 10,
  },
  SubmitButtonStyle: {
    marginTop: 10,
    paddingTop: 15,
    paddingBottom: 15,
    marginLeft: 30,
    marginRight: 30,
    backgroundColor: '#00BCD4',
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#fff',
    shadowOpacity: 0.5,
    shadowColor: 'blue',
    height: 50,
    width: 100,
  },

  SubmitButtonStyle2: {
    marginTop: 10,
    paddingTop: 15,
    paddingBottom: 15,
    marginLeft: 30,
    marginRight: 30,
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#fff',
    shadowOpacity: 0.5,
    shadowColor: 'blue',
    height: 50,
    width: 100,
  },
  TextStyle: {
    color: '#fff',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  TextStyle1: {
    color: 'black',
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontFamily: 'Cochin',
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
});

export default PhoneInput;
```

[image]

Comment: Where did you add the `justifyContent`? In which style object?

Comment: at the first view  container

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `marginRight` from `SubmitButtonStyle` and the `marginLeft` from `SubmitButtonStyle2` and you should be fine.

Comment: i want all the buttons to come into the middle of the screen .if i remove the marginRight and marginLeft will only bring the buttons together

Comment: Your comment makes no sense.

Comment: i dont get you please am a beginner in this react native please.what i want is this the main view to start at the middle of the screen.meaning.when you click at that photo above you will see the main view starts at the top

Comment: First, apologies. My comment was rather rude. I think I do now understand what you mean. You want to center everything vertically. Then I don't know what to say. What you did was fine. Sorry for not being able to help more.